# Dual space of locally convex space separates points

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Why does the following theorem fail if $X$ is not locally convex?

> Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space. Then $X^*$ separates points.

I understand the proof and where it uses local convexity of $X.$ However, I fail to understand this intuitively. I would like some intuition on why this happens.

**Edit:** $L^p[0,1],0<p<1$ is not locally convex and it has no non-zero linear functional. So I do have a counter-example. I'm just looking for intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your counter-example provides an intuition. 
" The existence of a convex local base for the zero vector is strong enough for the Hahn–Banach theorem to hold, yielding a sufficiently rich theory of continuous linear functionals." If the space is not locally convex, there might not be any(or sufficient) linear functionals to ensure separation.

Comment: I don't really see how this provides any intuition - it sounds almost like "local convexity is needed because without local convexity it might not work"

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not quite going to say that if $X^*$ separates points then $X$ must be locally convex, but it *does* follow that there are a lot of convex open sets in $X$.

For example, if $X^*$ separates points then the convex open sets separate points: Given $x\ne0$, choose $\Lambda\in X^*$ with $\Lambda x=1$. Let $V=\{y:|\Lambda y|<1/2\}$ and $W=\{y:|1-\Lambda y|<1/2\}$; then $V$ and $W$ are disjoint convex open sets, $0\in V$ and $x\in W$.

Comment: But intuitively, what's so special about local convexity that ensures $X^*$ separates points?

Comment: @SahibaArora $X^{\ast}$ separates points if and only if any two points have disjoint convex neighbourhoods. The sufficiency is one form of the Hahn-banach theorems, the necessity is clear because the preimages of disjoint convex neighbourhoods of the image points are disjoint convex neighbourhoods of the points. Local convexity (+ Hausdorffness) trivially implies that any two points can be separated by convex neighbourhoods. But local convexity is not a necessary condition, as the $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ spaces for $0 < p < 1$ show.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think I get it now. Thanks.